# Java: How to connect to mysql and redhsift hosted in AWS?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-redshift, remote-desktop

I am trying to do some automation in mysql and redshift usin Java (JDBC) preferred. I usually use a remote desktop connection to connect, from there I use mysql workbench and aginity workbench to access mysql and redshift repectively. I have authentication for both as well as the aws urls.Also the aginity license. My goal is to connect Java running outside the remote desktop, to query some data fro mthe databases and  compare them. I would like to know how to connect to both databases, as well as the documentation where I can learn more. I familiar with all three technologies , I just now sure how to connect them together. I am lost ,kidnle help. Thanks in advance.